# Why am I getting invalid_client with this POST request?

Tags: javascript, post, npm, http-post, httprequest

I am trying to communicate with an external API that has the following specification:

```
Host: name.of.host
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Using the `request` module of `npm`, I am building the POST request as follows:

```
function post2(uri, headerObj, bodyObj, bodyStr) {
  console.log("Posting to " + uri + " . . .");

  var options = {
    uri: uri,
    form: bodyObj,
    qs: bodyObj,
    method: 'POST',
    json: false,
    headers: headerObj
  };

  request(options, function(error, response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(error, response.body);
    return;
  });
}
```

The header and body objects are set up as follows:

```
var headerObj = {
    'Host': 'name.of.host',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
};

var bodyObj = {
  'client-id': 'GUID',
  'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
  'refresh_token': 'alpha-numeric data that also includes / = and + chars'
};
```

I double checked that the `client-id` and `refresh_token` elements contain the right data. I also tested the request with the same above contents on Postman and it works without any issues. Nonetheless, I still get the following error from the API:

`null '{"error":"invalid_client"}'`

I referred to the documentation on [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) regarding the `request` npm module and followed the **request(options, callback)** since the `request.post` **does not seem to allow you to enter any headers**. What am I doing wrong?

**-- EDIT --**

So now I tried using XMLHttpRequest instead and set the same exact headers. First I got a `Refused to set unsafe header "Host"` error so I removed the Host header and tried again. This time round I got no errors but no response was printed on cmd either (I'm using node to deploy).

This is my code:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", '/connect/token', true);

  //Send the proper header information along with the request
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Host", "name.of.host");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status == 200) {
      // Request finished. Do processing here.
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
  xhr.send("client-id=guid&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=tokenstuff");
```

I don't understand what could possibly be wrong. I am not seeing outgoing requests on the browser but an attempt is definitely being made because I can see the logs from node cmd.

Comment: Can you pop open the network tab of your browser's debug tools and see what the request looks like? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/

Comment: Ah, did you intend for the value of `bodyObj.'client-id'` to be a hard-coded string, "GUID" ?

Comment: @komali_2 Of course not. It represents a typical guid format string.

Comment: What the external API doc say about `"error":"invalid_client"`?

Comment: Are you intending to make use of both the `qs` and `form` option properties? Apart from this everything looks well formed, i.e your headers. I would check the API docs as @CastroRoy has suggested.

Comment: @jablesauce lol don't get spicy with me, sometimes an honest simple mistake like that is the problem.

Comment: @RichardWatts I included them because it seems that without them the POST request does not attach the query string.

Comment: @komali_2 Sorry, but I am definitely sure it is in the correct format because I directly copied from the Postman request, which worked :-)

Comment: To all - please review the edit I made on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple:

```
var bodyObj = {
  'client-id': 'GUID', // note how the key contains a dash 
  'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
  'refresh_token': 'alpha-numeric data'
};
```

This, on the other hand, works:

```
var bodyObj = {
      'client_id': 'GUID', // switch to underscore 
      'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
      'refresh_token': 'alpha-numeric data'
    };
```

Syntax errors are the worst.